# is there a better way to find how many times a character appears in an array or string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, character, counting

I'm still learning C and I've been trying to figure out the best way to count occurrences of characters in an array.

I plan on separating it into functions and expanding on it a lot but so far the best working code I've come up with is a bigger version of this:

```
#define SIZEONE 7
#define SIZETWO 3


int main(void)
{
    int arrOne[SIZEONE] = {97, 97, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99};
    char arrTwo[SIZETWO] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int arrThree[SIZETWO] = {0};
    int countOne = 0;
    int countTwo = 0;
    int countThree = 0;
    
    for(countOne = 0; countOne < SIZEONE; countOne++)
    {
        for(countTwo = 0; countTwo < SIZETWO; countTwo++)
        {
            if(arrOne[countOne] == arrTwo[countTwo])
            {
                arrThree[countTwo] = arrThree[countTwo] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(countThree = 0; countThree < SIZETWO; countThree++)
    {
        printf("%c ",arrTwo[countThree]);
    }
    
    countThree = 0;
    printf("\n");
    
    for(countThree = 0; countThree < SIZETWO; countThree++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arrThree[countThree]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From this I should get something that looks like:

> a b c
>
> 2 1 4

I'm just wondering if there is a simpler way to do this that someone can point me towards or give me an example of before I start using this method.

Comment: I indented your code so it is more readable.  Also, the definition of main can be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`.  `return` is not a function, so `return (0)` looks confusing; I removed the parentheses.

Comment: 1)always indent. 2) give your arrays meaningful names, this is unintelligible (for example input_characters, counter_array, etc. 3) iterate over arrays with i,j,k like everybody else does.

Comment: are you asking: how Do i count the number of occurrences of each letter in arrTwo in arrOne?

Comment: Sorry for the indentation and variable names, I wasn't even aware that it was common practice to just name those counter variables i,j,k. I was writing out a much smaller version of the code on my external to ask this question. I wanted to find the occurrences of arrTwo in arrOne, so how many a's b's and c's appeared (in ascii).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to insert this function as an example for all array sizes :

```
int findOccurences(const char *array, const int array_size, const char ch_to_find)
{
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] == ch_to_find) found++;  
    }
    return found;
}
```

It's a better practice to name your variables with a significant name. This will be easier to read for you and for others that can read your code.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the variables, I was just writing it from memory because my external was being used. This looks very useful though thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) you get less code:

```
long count[1u << CHAR_BIT]; 

char *text = "The string we want to count characters in";
long i;

// Clear count array
memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

// Count characters
for (i = strlen(text) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  count[(unsigned char)text[i]]++;
}

// Print occurance:
for (i = 0; i < 1u << CHAR_BIT; i++) {
  if (count[i] > 0) {
    printf("%4c", i);
  }
}
printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < 1u << CHAR_BIT; i++) {
  if (count[i] > 0) {
    printf("%4ld", count[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: This looks very promising thank you. I didn't know what that '1u' meant, after googling it am I right in thinking it is just a representation of 1?

Comment: Yes, it is the unsigned representation. It is good practice to use unsigned entities when using the bit shift operators, although in this particular case it doesn't really matter. I do it as a habit. On most platforms `1u << CHAR_BITS` is the same as `256`.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to define a counting array of 256 (or 127 for ascii only) zero it and for each occurrence increment to counting array.

```
void count_chars(char* arr)
{
  int counting[256],i;
  memset(counting,0,sizeof(counting));
  for(i=0; arr[i];++i){
    ++counting[(unsigned char)arr[i]];
  }
  for(i=0; i<256;++i){
    if(counting[i]){
      printf("%c - %d\n", (char)i, counting[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what a counting array is to be honest, thanks for mentioning it I will read up on it!

Comment: see the example. there is array named 'counting'. you can try to run the function. I fixed a bug I had so now it will work.